# Read property of a validation rule in CakePHP 3.x for use in a js function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a validation rule in one of my `Table` classes like this:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->scalar('comment')
        ->maxLength('comment', 3000)
        ->requirePresence('comment', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('comment');

    return $validator;
}
```

This validates the `comment` field of an input and means it cannot be over 3000 characters in length. All of this is fine when working in PHP.

One part of my application uses a JavaScript character counter - it tells the user how many remaining characters they have in a field as they type. The js for this works fine, with the limit 3000 hardcoded.

However, I want to know if there's a way to avoid hardcoding this limit in my js? Because otherwise my code is not DRY as I'm defining the 3000 limit in multiple places and if it changes that's problematic to remember/update.

Is it possible to read the `maxLength` property directly from `validationDefault` for the `comment` field? This question concerns how to access the data defined in the Table class; I am fine with knowing how to pass it to js via ajax.

I haven't got any further code to show as I don't know if/how this is even possible.

CakePHP 3.5.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get validation rule value, you have to get `Validator` from `Table`, then get `ValidationSet`, and then `ValidationRule`, from which you can extract desired result. Sample controller code below:

```
$validator = $this->YourTable->getValidator("default");
$validationSet = $validator->field("comment");
$validationRule = $validationSet->rule("maxLength");
$result = $validationRule->get("pass");
```

Or, in just one line:

```
$result = $this->YourTable->getValidator("default")->field("comment")->rule("maxLength")->get("pass");
```

A returned value will be an array of additional arguments passed to validation rule, in your case it should look like:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
      int(3000)
}
```

Also, @ndm in his answer mentioned about other posibilities:

> On form helper/context level it's also possible to read the schema, and support for transalting its length configuration and the validation rule value into a maxlength HTML attribute is being implemented for CakePHP 3.7

Further reading:

[Getting validators from tables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#getting-validators-from-tables)

[Validator class](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Validation.Validator.html)

[ValidationSet class](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Validation.ValidationSet.html)

[ValidationRule class](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Validation.ValidationRule.html)

Comment: Looks like you beat me by a few seconds... maybe you can add a note about the upcoming automatic handling of length schema configuration and max length validation rules too, then I can delete my answer.

Comment: @ndm - sure, I added this info.

Comment: For presenceRequired/allowEmpty validation check, use $this->YourTable->getValidator("default")->field("comment")->isPresenceRequired/isEmptyAllowed();